# Tensorboard visualizations of keras' embedding layer

Tags: keras, tensorboard, embedding

I have a CNN for a NLP classification project built in Keras. I have the embedding layer and then the callback:

```python
tbCallback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs/',
                     histogram_freq=10,
                     write_graph=False,
                     embeddings_freq=10,
                     batch_size=32,
                     embeddings_layer_names=['embedding'],
                     embeddings_metadata=embeddingsMetadata
                     )
```

The CNN is able to predict with 95% F1 and accuracy, so the CNN is indeed trained.

However, when I see the Tensorboard's projector, the words are not related at all, e.g. nearest words to company are water, food, hotdog (and I think this is not correct based on my training set).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know if you figured this out on your own but prior to June 2018 (not sure which exact version) [the embeddings for Keras are actually the weight of the layer and not the layer output](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6674). This should be fixed in more recent versions.